# Update Service Group in WSO2 Application Server

Tags: java, web-services, wso2

Problem :
I am facing difficulty in updating a service group in WSO2 Application server.

Environment details :
WSO2 Application Server 5.2.1
Using Eclipse to create Java Classes
Using option "Services -> JarService" to create service in WSO2

Scenario :
I create web services using the option "Services -> jarservice" in WSO2 from a Jar which had multiple classes implemented (lets say 6 methods in 6 classes). I was given an option to create a Service Group Name while doing this procedure. I have given a service group name (lets say Utilities). I was able to find all the services getting created under this group which is what I expected.

But here comes the problem. I wanted to create another service under the same service group (which is usual in any practical scenario). I am unable to do so. Any pointers on this?

[image: WSO2 Application Server : Service Group Properties]

Tried hard to find pointers on this but I was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Application server UI does not have request functionality. I.e. adding another service to an existing service group.

But you can update the services.xml of the service archive (.aar file). You can download this archive from the services list page of the UI.